# How to show 24 hours clock on matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a simple function and i want the x label to jump evry 10 minute.

for exemple

plot(hh:mm,y);

how do i show the time in 24 hours format on matlab?

Comment: yes i saw it but i dont Understand how to use it on my function

Comment: You haven't given us enough detail to help you (the code of your function, sample data, etc.). All we can do is point you to existing duplicates.

Comment: i want to plot x and y, and i want x to rise in scale of 10min. the problom is i dont know how to show on the plot the time, for exemple 00:10 or 14:30